# Duplicate Form Field Input Django

Tags: django, validation, django-forms, django-validation

So lets say I have two fields called `Member1` and `Member2` and both these fields belong in the same `Class` or `table`. A user will input values into these two fields via a `ModelForm`. How can I ensure that these two fields are not duplicates of each other. Here is my current validation code:

```
def clean(self):
    member1 = User.objects.filter(username__iexact=self.Member1.lower())
    member2 = User.objects.filter(username__iexact=self.Member2.lower())

    if member2 == member3:
        raise  ValidationError("Can't have duplicate team members")
```

But it is not working, 
Any ideas?

`View.py`

```
        if request.method == 'POST':
            form = CreateTeamForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
            if form.is_valid():
                instance = form.save(commit=False)
                instance.team_creator = request.user.id
                p2=None
                p3=None
                p4=None
                if instance.team_member2:
                    instance.team_member2 = User.objects.values('id').filter(username=instance.team_member2)[0]['id']
                    p2 = Profile.objects.get(user_id=instance.team_member2)
                    p2.team_id = instance.Team_ID
                    p2.save()
                if instance.team_member3:
                    instance.team_member3 = User.objects.values('id').filter(username=instance.team_member3)[0]['id']
                    p3 = Profile.objects.get(user_id=instance.team_member3)
                    p3.team_id = instance.Team_ID
                    p3.save()
                if instance.team_member4:
                    instance.team_member4 = User.objects.values('id').filter(username=instance.team_member4)[0]['id']
                    p4 = Profile.objects.get(user_id=instance.team_member4)
                    p4.team_id = instance.Team_ID
                    p4.save()

                instance.save()
```

Comment: You should put the `clean()` method in form. Where have you put it?

Answer (score 0):

You should get `Member1` and `Member2` from `cleaned_data` property:

```
def clean(self):
    data = self.cleaned_data
    member1 = User.objects.filter(username__iexact=data['Member1'].lower())
    member2 = User.objects.filter(username__iexact=data['Member2'].lower())

    if member1 == member2:
        raise  ValidationError("Can't have duplicate team members")

    return data
```

Comment: for some reason it says, 'Team' object has no attribute 'cleaned_data' and `Team` is the name of the model

Comment: I posted the view

Comment: all looks good. perhaps you instantiating `form = CreateTeamForm(request.POST, request.FILES)` twice?